# Error while passing FormData containing text and image in Angular 8

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular8, multipartform-data

I have an Angular Form where I am entering some text fields and an image field, and I am bundling them together with FormData() and then passing them on to my service.

Here is my HTML file:-

```
<body>
    <a routerLink="/"><img id="mainLogo" src="../../assets/images/main-logo-resized.PNG" alt="Go to main page"></a>
    <input type="button" id="logoutBtn" (click)="onLogout()" value="Logout">
    <div class="genericForm">
        <form #sellBookForm="ngForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" (ngSubmit)="sellBookForm.valid && onSubmit(sellBookForm)">
            <h1>Tell us about your book</h1>
            <input type="text" #bookName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="bookService.selectedBook.bookName" name="bookName" placeholder="Name of book" required autofocus [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox': sellBookForm.submitted && !bookName.valid}">
            <div *ngIf="sellBookForm.submitted && !bookName.valid">
                <label class="validation-message">This field is required!</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="text" #authorName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="bookService.selectedBook.authorName" name="authorName" placeholder="Name of author" required [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox': sellBookForm.submitted && !authorName.valid}">
            <div *ngIf="sellBookForm.submitted && !authorName.valid">
                <label class="validation-message">This field is required!</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="text" #publisherName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="bookService.selectedBook.publisherName" name="publisherName" placeholder="Name of publisher" required [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox': sellBookForm.submitted && !publisherName.valid">
            <div *ngIf="sellBookForm.submitted && !publisherName.valid">
                <label class="validation-message">This field is required!</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="text" #price="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="bookService.selectedBook.price" name="price" placeholder="Price" required ngClass="{'invalid-textbox': sellBookForm.submitted && !price.valid}">
            <div *ngIf="sellBookForm.submitted && !price.valid">
                <label class="validation-message">This field is required!</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="file" #bookImg="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="bookService.selectedBook.bookImg" name="bookImg" accept="image/*" id="bookImg" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" required ngClass="{'invalid-textbox': sellBookForm.submitted && !bookImg.valid}">
            <label for="bookImg" id="bookImgLabel"><img src="../../assets/images/upload-image-resized.png" alt="Upload">Upload book image</label>
            <div *ngIf="sellBookForm.submitted && !bookImg.valid">
                <label class="validation-message">This field is required!</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sell now!">
        </form>
    </div>
    <a routerLink="/marketplace" class="backToMarketplaceLink">Back to marketplace</a>
</body>
```

Here is my Component file:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { BookService } from '../shared/book.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sell-page',
  templateUrl: './sell-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sell-page.component.css']
})
export class SellPageComponent implements OnInit {

  // Variable to get the book image file
  bookImg;

  // Boolean variable to show/hide div element is case of successful book submission
  showSuccessMessage: boolean;

  // Error messages in case book submission failed
  serverErrorMessages: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private bookService: BookService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onFileSelected(event) {
    this.bookImg = event.target.files[0];
    document.getElementById('bookImgLabel').innerHTML = this.bookImg.name;
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('bookData', JSON.stringify(form.value));
    formData.append('bookImg', this.bookImg, this.bookImg.name);
    this.bookService.postBook(formData).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.showSuccessMessage = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showSuccessMessage = false;
        }, 1000);
      },
      err => {
        if (err.status === 422) {
          this.serverErrorMessages = err.error.join('<br/>');
        } else {
          this.serverErrorMessages = 'Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.';
        }
      }
    );
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.userService.deleteToken();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }

}
```

I am getting an error in `this.bookService.postBook(formData).subscribe()`:-

```
Argument of type 'FormData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Book'.
  Type 'FormData' is missing the following properties from type 'Book': bookName, authorName, publisherName, price, bookImg
```

This is my Service file:-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Book } from './book.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {

  selectedBook: Book = {
    bookName: '',
    authorName: '',
    publisherName: '',
    price: 0,
    bookImg: null
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // HTTP methods

  postBook(book: Book) {
    return this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + '/sell', book);
  }
}
```

This service file is using a Model Class file:-

```
export class Book {
    bookName: string;
    authorName: string;
    publisherName: string;
    price: number;
    bookImg: File;
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error because I have appended the entire form value along with the image file in the `formData` variable in the Component file. Can I not use FormData() along with a model to pass info? Please help, I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postBook Method in BookService you are expecting a Parameter type of Book Class , but you are using FormData in the component.
There’s number of ways to fix this:

1. Change parameter type to FormData in postBook.
2. You can use selectedBook field in service since you are binding the values in there, except the img which needs a single formData For it.

Comment: I tried both approaches, and I feel the first one is easier. Thanks!